# Does an ajax callback work within a Views style plugin?

Tags: views, 8, ajax

My module has a custom Views style plugin. In the style settings form, I want to implement an ajax callback, such as described here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms

However, I haven't had any luck. I can get a spinning effect, but nothing happens afterward. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;  

  public function TestCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $text = 'Text to see if this is working';
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#foo', $text));

    return $ajax_response;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['test'] = [
      '#title' => t('TEST!'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => [
        '' => t('None'),
        'foo' => t('Bar'),
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => '::TestCallback',
    // having the line below uncommented seems to help        
    //'url' => views_ui_build_form_url($form_state),
      ],
      '#prefix' => '<div id="foo"></div>',
      '#default_value' => '',
    ];
  }
```

If I uncomment the commented 'url', I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
at resetSize (<anonymous>:34:32)
at later (debounce.js?v=8.6.3:20)
```

If I keep it commented, I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () 
/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/view_name/page_1/style_options? 
_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax:1
Uncaught Drupal.AjaxError
ajax.js?v=8.6.3:500
```

What's missing and/or incorrect?

Comment: I believe it could have something to do about a missing form ID for the style plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand seeing the [AJAX docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms#ajax_callback_function), I think you're not supposed to return an `AjaxResponse` object. You're supposed to return a renderable array from the Ajax callback.

### Sample Code

```
public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
  $form['test'] = [
    '#title' => t('TEST!'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => [
      '' => t('None'),
      'foo' => t('Bar'),
    ],
    '#ajax' => [
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'ajax-output-container',
      // Since views style options forms are complex, they're built by
      // Drupal in a different way. To bypass this problem we need to
      // provide the full path to the Ajax callback.
      'callback' => __CLASS__ . '::testCallback',
    ],
    '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-output-container"></div>',
    '#default_value' => '',
  ];
}

/**
 * This is the AJAX callback.
 *
 * It generates the output for the AJAX request. The output REPLACES
 * the "wrapper" you define in #ajax.
 */
public function testCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // This element will replace the DIV#foo you have in your #prefix.
  $elem = [
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<div id="ajax-output-container">Is it not working!></div>',
  ];
  return $elem;
}
```

### Debugging

- Make sure that on page load, you're getting a div with the correct ID in your field prefix. You can put some default text in the prefix so that you can see it on page load?
- If HTML tags are being stripped from your `#prefix` markup for some reason, then try injecting a separate item in the form with `#markup`.

Comment: Thanks for including the sample code. I'm still getting the same errors, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message backtrace? Can you see in the network tab of the dev console to check what output Drupal is returning for the AJAX request?

Comment: OK, I'm getting this in the DB log: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php).

Comment: If I click on the URL in the network tab, I also see this: 
[{
 "command": "insert",
 "method": "prepend",
 "selector": null,
 "data": "\n\n\u003C!-- THEME DEBUG ... BEGIN OUTPUT from \u0027core\/themes\/classy\/templates\/misc\/status-messages.html.twig\u0027 --... Error message\u003C\/h2\u003E\n                    An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (100 MB) that this server supports.\n                \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \n\u003C!-- END OUTPUT ...",
 "settings": null
}]

Comment: I had to add the double colons and the rest works for me correctly.

Comment: Followed the debugging steps, but still the same issues. What Style plugin have you been testing this on?

Comment: Tried this on a custom styles plugin I was working on. Now it should work for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88710/discussion-between-jigar-mehta-and-andileco).

Comment: The addition of "'callback' => __CLASS__ . '::testCallback'," makes it work!

Answer (score 0):

$route_name = "views_ui.form_{$form_key}"; might be the problem.

Try to print somewhere this result under buildOptionsForm function and see if it is the problem: views_ui_build_form_url($form_state)->toString();

If You keep it commented, error happens because their is no url nor '#wrapper' which is needed for ajax.

Here you can investigate this error deeper:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21admin.inc/function/views_ui_build_form_url/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe experiencing an issue related to this [Drupal core issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2504115). See this [issue comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2504115#comment-12886335) and [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2504115#comment-12891279) about implementing a work-around.